# How to get Mambo 4.5.5 and Joomla! 1.0.15 to recent Joomla?

Tags: migration

Among sites I manange there are two which are still running very old installations:

- Mambo 4.5.5 Stable
- Joomla! 1.0.15 Stable

There was no practical need of migration last years, they have only minor content updates, they run stable having almost no extensions and the only active user is *administrator*.

I understand migration of their content might need more than one phase but I'm fine with that. **Could you please help me with drawing the upgrade path?** I think Mambo should be taken first to J! 1.0, then both 1.0 sites to J! 1.5 and then both to 2.5/3.X.  Correct?

Content I'd like to preserve – only core-related stuff:

- articles (*static content items* and standard content items) [about 200]
- categories (/sections) [about 50]
- menu items [about 50]
- web links [about 30]
- content of custom HTML modules [about 15]

Is semi-automatic migration viable or should I think of copy-paste manual work as of faster and less painful solution?

Comment: Copy and past is maybe the better solution, if you are less experienced with joomla and databse conflicts. You have round about 350 items to copy and pasty. If you need for every item 1 minute, then you can do this task in 7 hours. If you try migrating the content you can do this maybe in 1 - 2 hours. But if you have any problems, it can be very time consuming to solve them(maybe more than 7 hours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you start anything, make sure you have a backup of both sites just incase any mistakes are made in the process.

For migrating Mambo to Joomla 1.0, have a look at the following tutorial.

http://help.joomla.org/content/view/818/181/

you will need to download a copy of Joomla 1.0 for this which you can get from here:

http://mirror.phil-taylor.com/

Once done, the next step is to upgrade to Joomla 1.5. Have a read of this detailed guide on how to do so:

http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable

The link to the Migrator is broken but the Migrator can be found at:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=430&t=388744&p=2990436#p2990436

Now comes the easier part, upgrading to Joomla 2.5, but firstly, ensure you have the latest version of Joomla 1.5 which is 1.5.26. To upgrade to 2.5, you can use [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) which is a component that does all the work for you. Simply install it and following the instructions.

Once upgraded, you should see that you're now running Joomla 2.5.20. From now on, you can upgrade to a newer Joomla version using the 1 click update feature built into the Joomla backend. Simply go to **Components** (top menu) >> **Joomla! Update**. You may need to click on the Options button and select "Short Term Support" to upgrade from Joomla 2.5.x to Joomla 3.x.

The whole process of migrating and upgrading may take a little time as there are a fair amount of things to be done.

Good luck and hope this helps